# Are Pokemon Brilliant Diamond and Shining Pearl using controller vibrations or motion?

Tags: controllers, pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

I like to play handheld with Split Pad controllers because size does matter, but they lack vibrations and gyroscope.
Game informed me that motion controls will be used somewhere in game, but it can be disabled in options so its probably optional.

Will I miss some features without vibrations/hd-rumble?

Answer (score 1):

I have had motion controls enabled the entire game. I am currently past the elite four and pretty far through all the post game content. Even so, I could not tell you a point where I have actually used motion controls.

Even doing some googling, it does appear like others are unable to figure out what the motion controls are even used for. It appears as if they are not actually used in the game. I thought they might have been usable in the contests but I have completed Master Rank on every contest and still haven't used motion controls.

In terms of vibration, no you will not miss out anything, it is just extra vibrations when things happen.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that vibration, motion controls, and touchscreen, are only cosmetic features.

Vibration:

- Feedback during digging in Grand Underground.
  [image: BZZZZT when pickaxing]

Motion Control:

- Chorus (left joycon) and Filter (right joycon) in *Cry* screen in Pokedex.
  [image: shake it, baby]

Touch Screen:

- Grand Underground digging minigame.
- Poketch, an alternative to virtual cursor (Sticks/D-Pad). App change button can be accessed via touch screen when minimized by tapping it on screen.
  [image: half-useless UX disaster]